# ngx-masonry images are overlapping on load in angular

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7, angular8

I am facing an issue while loading images in ngx masonry. The images are overlapping on top of other. I have images with 2 different heights rendering dynamically. Please find my code below :

```
<div>
 <ngx-masonry  [useImagesLoaded]="true" class='carousel-indicators space-of-thumbnail' infinite-scroll (scrolled)="onScrollDown($event)" [scrollWindow]="false">
<div ngxMasonryItem class="masonry-item"  *ngFor="let image of images; let k=index">
      <div class="op-7" data-target='#carousel-custom'  [attr.data-slide-to]="k" >
                        <img class="width" [src]="image.attachments.data[0].thumb_uri" />
                    </div>
                </div>
</ngx-masonry>
</div>
```

- style is below:

```
.masonry-item {
    width : 50%; //2 images in a row
}
```

any solution to this?